# Cannot resolve class library

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

ASP.NET Core (.NET Core) can add a Class Library (.NET Core) as a reference but it couldn't resolve public classes or interfaces in the Class Library.

There is no error messages in adding reference, restoring packages and building the solution, until I want to use public interfaces or classes in the class library. The error message is: "Can't resolve the symbol "IMessagesService".

I searched in similar questions, there was just a solution about changing netstandard1.5 to 1.4 in project.json in the Class Library, but it didn't work. Both the main project and the class library are in the same folder (src). And there is just one global.json.

Global.Jason

```
 {
  "projects": [ "src", "test" ],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-preview2-003121"
  }
}
```

project.json in class library

```
    {
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.4": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}
```

project.json in main project (ASP.NET Core)

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "CoreWebApplicationTestServices": "1.0.0-*"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },
```

Reference added without any errors.

[image]

But there is error when I want to use the public interface in the class library
[image]

What did I do wrong? Or maybe it is a bug! 
Thanks a lot ...

Comment: Try disable Reshaper, in the past it was know that certain versions of Resharper cause issues with intellisense/runtime-validation. At least I suspect you are using Resharper as the error messages are highlighted differently than in vanilla VS2015

Comment: Yes, you right. This is a problem with Resharper. After add services.AddTransient<IMessagesService, MessagesService>(); to ConfigureServices method, application works properly but with error from Resharper not from compiler. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `"Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final"` to `"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0"`

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshots it seems you are using ReSharper. From the past it has been known that in certain versions of ReSharper design-time validation fails to work on (ASP).NET Core projects, the program compiles w/o errors though.

Disabling ReSharper should solve the issue.

Using a newer version of ReSharper may solve the issue, i.e.  the ReSharper 2016.2 EAP (Early Access Program) version, mentioned in [ReSharper Ultimate 2016.2 EAP kicks off](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2016/05/27/resharper-ultimate-2016-2-eap-kicks-off/).

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned in above comment the problem is from Resharper and unfortunately updated to newest version of Resharper doesn't solve the problem for me.